# Creating a Class from an XSD

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xsd

Here is my current situation.  I had to break standards for how to do web services calls.  We had 60+ WSDLs to connect to and the name changed based on a parameter.  I created the web service call dynamically using a WebClient and built the envelope manually (it was decided to do this instead of adding each web service by upper management).  I get a string response back that has the valid XML that matches the XSD.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a class to reference the fields dynamically instead of a class per WSDL (build a class based on the XSD being used).  Here is what I'm doing:

```
public string results;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string soapENV = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    var payload = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" +
                   "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='" + soapENV + "'>" +
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Header/>" + 
                       "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" + 
                         "<" + myParams.requestName + " xmlns='" +    
                             myParams.requestNamespace + "'>" +
                           "<MtvnSvcVer>1.0</MtvnSvcVer>" + 
                           "<MsgUUID>" + UUID + "</MsgUUID>" + 
                           "<PrcsParms>" + 
                           "<SrcID>" + currentVendorID + "</SrcID>" + 
                           "</PrcsParms>"
                           ................
                       "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" + 
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
   this.results = client.UploadString  (URL, payload);
}
```

For the sake of saving time and space I took out some of the XML tags.  The XSD response has the same values for XML tags as above.  I then call this to be executed as follows:

```
string results = connectwareService.InvokeConnectWare();
```

The results returned look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>        
    <DPNmeAddrInqMtvnSvcRes  xmlns="mtvnCWDPNmeAddrInqSvcRes"> 
     <MtvnSvcVer>1.0</MtvnSvcVer>
     <MsgUUID>DATA HERE</MsgUUID>           
      <Svc>
       <SvcParms>
         <ApplID>DATA HERE</ApplID>
         <SvcID>DATA HERE</SvcID>
         <SvcVer>1.0</SvcVer>
         <RqstUUID>DATA HERE</RqstUUID>
       </SvcParms>
       <MsgData>
       <DPNmeAddrInqResData xmlns="mtvnCWDPNmeAddrInqResData">
         <E20007>DATA HERE</E20007>
        ........    
   </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a way in the code to do this?  I keep seeing peopele refer to using xsd.exe.  Can that be executed in code behind?  I was thinking that I could read through and populate a generic class with the tag name as a name and the data as a value as last resort but there has to be a way to generate this on the fly in the code.  I guess another way I could do it is read all 60+ wsdls and run xsd.exe to build the classes needed?

Also,  Just some FYI - I'm converting old Cold Fusion code to C# and I'm trying to figure out how to replace its "ConvertXmlToStruct" method.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is awful for several reasons. First of all, what do you mean "the name changed based on a parameter"? Did the name of the service change, but the WSDL was otherwise the same? You don't need to do anything fancy to make that work. Second, don't _ever_ build XML by using string APIs. Use XML APIs to build XML. In particular, LINQ to XML allows you to build XML in a fairly readable manner.

Comment: Hey John,  The WSDL name changes.  So for example we have 5 systems, and each system has 10+ operations.  Based on the system/operation is how they have their wsdl being populated and conencted to.  So our services that we call are set up like this: "http://sameurl/system/operation.wsdl".  In regards to XML APIs and LINQ to XML, do you have any links or books I can refer to?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: But are the contents of each wsdl the same? is `sameurl/system1/operation.wsdl` the same as `sameurl/system2/operation.wsdl`? Keep in mind that the WSDL files are not being used at runtime. Quite likely, all you need to change at runtime is the endpoint to connect to (`https://sameurl/system2/operation.svc`).

Comment: As to the XML API, see [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: Hey John, the wsdls are not the same.  The way it was built is each WSDL has 1 web method each in it (I was told for security reasons they did it this way ".........").  Thanks for the link.  Some of the XML that is built is dynamic because some of the tags are required/not required depending on the method being called.  I build that dynamically based on the parameters passed from the calling program (Example: they pass me E11111 Account Number I build <E11111>Account Number</E11111> ).

Comment: If you really have 50 individual WSDLs, then I would still say you should not be doing this dynamically. As much of an initial pain as it may be, I think you should use svcutil.exe to generate 50 separate proxy classes.

Comment: Then, rather than having a general-purpose dispatch method that is called by various callers with different parameters, and which calls the correct service with the correct parameters, have the callers just call the correct method on the correct proxy class to begin with. You won't have to maintain this dispatch class, which is a single point of failure, and no doubt a single source of many bugs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xsd.exe is only run once to build a class file that represents the objects defined in the XSD.  You then use an XmlSerializer class to actually convert (aka deserialize) the XML to the c# class.

There are a lot of links out there talking about deserializing XML in C#:

[How to use xsd in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003952/how-to-use-xsd-in-c)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx

Comment: Hey Mike,  So would you suggest building all the classes from all t he XSD files and every time we add a new WSDL we just rebuild the XSD files to include the new class?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, every time you're looking to deserialize a new or updated object type (e.g. when you get a new XSD) you would need to regenerate the class files.

Answer (score 2):

XSD.exe worked great.  Please see my code I used below to make it work:

```
Process process = new Process();
        string arguments = @" " + row["OutputFileDirectory"].ToString() + row["XSDMainBuildName"].ToString() + " " + row["OutputFileDirectory"].ToString() + row["ImportNames"].ToString() + " /c /language:CS /out:" + row["OutputClassDirectory"].ToString() + " /namespace:" + row["Namespace"].ToString();
        string fileNameXSD = "";
        if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin"))
        {
            fileNameXSD = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\xsd.exe";
        }
        else
        {
            fileNameXSD = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin\xsd.exe";
        }
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileNameXSD;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        if (!DataValidator.ValidateFieldIsBlank(error))
        {
            lblOutputResults.Text = error;
        }
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

This was put in my code behind on my web form.  What this did was fire off the xsd.exe process for each item I selected to build.  This helped our company out with our calls A LOT.  Thanks to all who helped and gave additional information.